# Trouble with checkbox filtering

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm having problems with filtering a field that comes from an sql database. I have managed to make a textbox filter, but I'm having trouble making a checkbox one.

Here is the code I have right now

```
Dim bolean1 As Boolean

If (Me.checkbox1.Value) = True Then
    (Me.checkbox1.Value) = Boolean1 = 0
Else 
    Boolean1 = 1 And Me.checkbox1.Value = boolean1
End If

Dim Sql As String

Sql = " Select *From Database Where boolean = boolean1"

Me.List.RowSource = Sql
```

Comment: I just changed the variable name i dont call it that i usually give it a 3 digit identifier for example strTextbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably reduce it to:

```
Dim Boolean1 As Boolean
Dim Sql As String

Boolean1 = Me!Checkbox1.Value
Sql = "Select * From Database Where BooleanField = " & Str(Boolean1) & ""

Me.List.RowSource = Sql
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, dont name a column "Boolean", and dont declare a string as 'sql' Figure these words to be reserved.

Note your sql needs a space between * and F

Use parameters.

```
    Dim SqlConn As New SqlConnection("ConnectionString")
    Dim SqlCmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Tablw WHERE ColumnName =@ColumnName", SqlConn)
    SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = CheckBox1.Checked
```